# Outlook 2013 - Forward Messages When Added to a Folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

We use Outlook 2013 to access Microsoft Hosted Office 365 email accounts.  I'm trying to setup "something" where if I move an email from the Inbox to an Outlook folder that, in addition to adding it to that Outlook folder, forwards that message to a particular individual.

Is it possible to forward all emails added to a folder at the time they are added?

Comment: Is this a case where the emails will always be going to the same folder?  Or even a case where there are only a few folders that this type of rule will need to run on?  Because gut reaction is to do it with VBA/Macro rather than relying on the move action triggering the forward.

Comment: Normally what would happen is a rule would catch what emails are added (E.G. 'Bob' in Subject line -> Move to folder 'Bob' and forward to Bob). The rule itself would only need to apply when someone outside our department doesn't put 'Bob' in the subject line on accident. In that case, someone could see the message and say, "Oh, this needs to go in the 'Bob' folder, I'll move it there manually." When that happens, I'd let to make it so that 'Bob' also gets the message forwarded to. It's a little more complicated than I'm describing, so I'd like to avoid necessitating manual forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy with VBA macros. Consider the following example:

```vb
Public WithEvents FolderItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set FolderItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("My Folder").Items
End Sub

Private Sub FolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    Set msg = item.Forward
    msg.Recipients.Add "John Doe"
    msg.Send
End Sub
```

After restarting Outlook, it will forward any new messages that appears in the **Inbox\My Folder** will be forwarded to **John Doe** automatically.

Comment: Excellent, I'm not familiar with VBA so I wasn't sure if this was possible. Now I know where to look!