# Forward Messages in Folder from Web

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, forwarding

I have a problem [similar to this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/989435/outlook-2013-forward-messages-when-added-to-a-folder), but slightly different.

How can I automatically forward all emails when added to a folder **from the web interface**? We're using Office 365 Business.

I'd like something similar to the effect of "Enable Forwarding", but without using that option. Also this would enable me to have a backup of also the sent emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to create a rule to automatically forward messages on the web?
Also, copies of messages that you redirect or forward will remain in your mailbox.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-rules-to-automatically-forward-messages-45aa9664-4911-4f96-9663-ece42816d746

Comment: Do you think my reply is helpful? If so, please kindly mark it as answer.

Comment: Thank you, it solved it!